# R mutate which.max by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm running into an issue that I feel should be simple but cannot figure out and have searched the board for comparable problems/question but unable to find an answer.

In short, I have data from a variety of motor vehicles and looking to know the average speed of the vehicle when it is at maximal acceleration. I also want the opposite - the average acceleration at top speed.

I am able to do this for the whole dataset using the following code

```
data<-data %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(speedATaccel= with(data, avg.Speed[which.max(top.Accel)]),
         accelATspeed= with(data, avg.Accel[which.max(top.Speed)]))
```

However, the group_by function doesn't appear to be working it just provide the values across the whole dataset as opposed to each individual vehicle group.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `with(data`, disrupt the `group_by` attribute and get the index on the whole data.  Instead, use tidyverse methods, i.e. remove the `with(data`.  Note that in `tidyverse`, we don't need to use any of the base R extraction methods i.e. with `$` or `[[` or `with`, instead specify the unquoted column name

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
      group_by(Name) %>%
      mutate(speedATaccel = avg.Speed[which.max(top.Accel)],
              accelAtspeed = avg.Accel[which.max(top.Speed)])
```